# CGContextFillPath does not seem to work in a loop

Tags: iphone, objective-c

This is the base simplified code, no matter what I've tried the colour does not change
I tried individually for 0,1,2 and it works and fills the path with the proper color
but in a loop color does not change.

I tried: mutablepath , saving/restoring the context, running a clean, some permutations of the code and so far not much success, it looks so terrible simple but cannot see what I'm missing.

```
for(looper=0; looper<MAX ; looper++)
{ 
        CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [[self setMyColor:lopper] CGColor]);


        [self draw_a_path:context ... more dimension args];


        CGContextClosePath(context);
        CGContextFillPath(context);
}

-(UIColor *) setMyColor:(int ) for_this_idx
{
UIColor *cur_color;

switch(for_this_idx)
{
    case 0: 
        cur_color = [UIColor colorWithRed: 0xdf/255.0 green: 0x01/255.0 blue: 0x01/255.0 alpha: 1.0] ;  
                    break;
      ... more cases ...
}
return cur_color;
}      

-(void) draw_a_path:(CGContextRef) thisContext
            ... position args ... 
{
... more stuff with Arcs but basically is this and each case works individually with the proper colour ....

CGContextMoveToPoint(thisContext, x_start,y_start);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(thisContext, x_start + n1), y_start + n2) );
CGContextAddLineToPoint(thisContext, x_start + n1 + p1), y_start + n2 + p2) );
CGContextAddLineToPoint(thisContext, x_start, y_start);
```

...
   }

Comment: We need to see the code for `setMyColor:` and `draw_a_path:`.

Comment: Is your intention to animate a colour change, in an on-screen view?

Comment: I just have a few shapes I need to draw filled with different colours

Comment: I don't see a call to `CGContextBeginPath`.  Do you have one?

Comment: You also have a typo in your example - you're passing "lopper" instead of "looper" to setMyColor:.

Comment: I did have a CGContextBeginPath it didn't make a difference, sorry for typos on the pseudo-code... no point on throwing all of the gory details